# Calling Skim from inside R

Tags: r, pdf

I'm making a simple line in r to automatically open my generated plots.

I output the plots to a file called "plots.pdf" in the same directory as my r file, and at the end i use this two lines to try to open it:

```
dir <- paste("/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/MacOS/Skim ",getwd(),"/plots.pdf",sep="")
system(dir)
```

Basically, dir concatenates the full path of the skim app and the full path of the generated plot.

If i run the string stored at dir in a shell it works perfect, it opens the pdf file in Skim, but when i run it with system() from inside R it doesn't work (Skim says 'The document “plots.pdf” could not be opened.').

I believe this is a very little mistake somewhere in the syntax regarding the absolute/relative paths, but haven't managed to find it... Any advice is welcome! (Or a better way to achieve the same)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to bypass that problem, i just changed the path to Skim for the 'open' command and i let the system to assign the default app for pdf viewing. So:

```
dir <- paste("open ",getwd(),"/plots.pdf",sep="")
```

And it works.